# Unable to load multiple pages of a PDF with React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, pdf, react-native-webview

Hope you are doing great today :) So I'm facing this issue with React Native. I'm trying to load a pdf (received in a base64 response) in my application, and the unique thing It worked for me its to use the WebView component from 'react-native-webview' package.

```
<View style={{ height: '100%', paddingVertical: 40 }} >
  <WebView source={{  html: `<embed width="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64, ${dataInBase64}" />` }} />
</View>
```

So the problem is that, despite I can see my pdf (which is awesome after hours of trying), I can't scroll through the rest of pages it have. In my application, I can see this:

[PDF preview in my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNFay.png)

And, on the other hand, the same html code in a plain html file shows in my browser what I was expecting, the possibility to scroll through all the pages of my file:

[PDF preview in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeRrw.png)

I don't care about the left navigation bar which shows all the thumbnail pages, I only want to load all the file content in my App.

So, what I'm expecting is to load all the content of my PDF files in my react native app, because right now it only loads the first page of the file, as if it were an image, without any horizontal scroll to the next pages.

I hope I make myself clear, but please ask me anything to clarify the problem.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh my god, so there is not workaround I can follow to fix this problem @KJ? I mean, in ten years they have to had think in a solution, I can't be the only one with this problem 

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `react-native-pdf` if previewing a pdf is your main objective.

For reference: [react-native-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey! So I didn't want to use any third party libraries but at the end it was the only way I've found to solve the problem, so yes, react-native-pdf was the solution I've followed but the one I wasn't wanted.